# parsing a lattitude and longitude from Json in to my app

Tags: json, google-maps, parsing, ios7

I'm trying to insert my Json Results in to my project

I have the following map set up an running with 2 pointers and a 3rd pointer for my location:

```
//create a marker for Car

GMSMarker *marker2 = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker2.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(+51.7849979425945, -1.485403844654244);

// change colour to green
UIColor *green;
green =[UIColor greenColor];
marker2.icon =[GMSMarker markerImageWithColor:green];

 }
```

also I get the data from the following code

```
 // WHEN VIEWCONTROLLER LOADS
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
[super viewDidLoad];

NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.dmk-media.com/taxi/json.php"];
NSURLRequest *request =[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
 (void) [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self]; }
```

if you go to the url you will see the data gets returned with just one line of Json

```
 [{"ID":"2","Longitude":"-1.485662152530882","Lat":"51.7847928765227","Date":"2013-12-13 22:46:15"}]
```

what I need to know is how I get the longitude and latitude from the Json results to the

```
marker2.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(+51.7849979425945, -1.485403844654244);
```

I have tried various helps and examples but I keep hitting a brick wall ive been at this for a while now please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:
in order to use lat and long out side that method do this:
In your .h file:

```
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *lat;
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSString *longi;
```

and in your .m file synethize those variables and in the void connection method (see the updated function now).

You have to parse your data from json format so that you can save your response in nsdicitionary than you will be able to read the values against every key. Follow this example .

```
-(void)fetchData{
    NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.dmk-media.com/taxi/json.php"];
    NSURLRequest *request =[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSURLConnection *conn=[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    [conn start];

}
```

New Update : for setting marker2.position

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
    NSError *error;
    NSArray* results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                       options:0
                                                         error:&error];
    NSDictionary *responseValues=[results objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"the resposne is %@",responseValues);
    lat=[responseValues objectForKey:@"Lat"];
   longi=[responseValues objectForKey:@"Longitude"];
   [self setMarkerPosition];

}
-(void)setMarkerPosition{
GMSMarker *marker2 = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker2.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat.FloatValue, longi.FloatValue);

// change colour to green
UIColor *green;
green =[UIColor greenColor];
marker2.icon =[GMSMarker markerImageWithColor:green];
```

}

you have to also include this line in your .h file.

```
UIViewController<NSURLConnectionDelegate,NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>
```

i have create the fetchData function that i am calling in my viewdidload method.

Comment: that has helped greatly and got me almost there but i need to use the lat and long  outside the -(void) connection but when i declare in the .h file as                                           @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *lat; the NSLog shows the correct output but the marker is way off in the equator. how can i use the value outside

Comment: yes you can do that as well. The NSString variable that are in the (void)connection method , just declare them in your .h file and than in this (void)connection method, insert the values like i have done and use the lat and long outside that method.

Comment: yes i know how to do that but the values dont get passed correctly. the marker shows up in the equator the NSLog shows fine But the Marker is wrong. declared in the .h file and sythased in the m file

Comment: in the .h file //// @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *lat; and so on. but nothing works. i have to code the outputs as marker2.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat.floatValue, longi.floatValue);

Comment: where are you calling the method in which you are setting marker2.position.

Comment: check my update answer and let me know if it is working or not.

Comment: no its not fetching in the data soon enough i think on -(void)setMarkerPosition the data value is null

Comment: if you have an email i can email the full .m file